# thread work if previously thread finished work (cuda) in same block

Tags: cuda, critical-section

hello I am a beginner in  cuda programming.I use lock.lock () function to wait for previously thread finished work. this my code :

```
#include "book.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include "lock.h"
#define pop 10
#define gen 10
#define pg pop*gen
using namespace std;
__global__ void hold(Lock lock,float* a )
{
    __shared__ int cache[gen];
int tid=blockIdx.x * blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
int cacheIndex = threadIdx.x;
if(tid<gen)
{
    a[tid]=7;//this number example but in my chase this random number
}
else
{
    //cache[cacheIndex]=a[tid];
    int temp;
        if(tid%gen==0)
        {

            a[tid]=tid+4;//this example number but in my chase this random number if tid==tid%gen
            temp=a[tid];
            tid+=blockIdx.x*gridDim.x;

        }
        else
        {
            __syncthreads();
            a[tid]=temp+1;//this must a[tid]=a[tid-1]+1;
            temp=a[tid];
            tid+=blockIdx.x*gridDim.x;

        }

    cache[cacheIndex]=temp;
    __syncthreads();
    for (int i=0;i<gen;i++)
    {
        if(cacheIndex==i)
        {
            lock. lock();
            cache[cacheIndex]=temp;
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }


}

}
int main()
{
float time;
float* a=new float [pg];
float *dev_a;

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a,pg *sizeof(int) ) );
Lock lock;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventCreate(&start) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventCreate(&stop) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventRecord(start, 0) );
hold<<<pop,gen>>>(lock,dev_a);
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( a, dev_a,pg * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventRecord(stop, 0) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventSynchronize(stop) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop) );
for(int i=0;i<pop;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<gen;j++)
    {
        cout<<a[(i*gen)+j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
printf("hold:  %3.1f ms \n", time);
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaFree(dev_a));
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventDestroy( start ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventDestroy( stop ) );
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

and this the result :

7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

24 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

34 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

44 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

54 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

74 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

84 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

94 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

my expected result :

7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

24 25 26 27 28 29 23 31 32 33

34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43

44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53

54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63

64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73

74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83

84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93

94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103

any one please help me to correct my code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want help, it would be useful to point out that some of your code (e.g. `lock.h` and `book.h`) come from the CUDA by examples book.  This is not a standard part of CUDA, so if you don't indicate where it comes from, it may be confusing.

I see the following issues in your code:

1. You are using a `__syncthreads()` in a conditional block where not all threads will meet the `__syncthreads()` barrier:

   ```
   if(tid%gen==0)
   {
     ...
   }
   else
   {
       __syncthreads();  // illegal

   }
   ```

   The usage of `__syncthreads()` in this way [is illegal](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions) because not all threads will be able to reach the `__syncthreads()` barrier:

> __syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block, otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended side effects.

2. You are using the `temp` local variable without initializing it first:

   ```
       a[tid]=temp+1;//this must a[tid]=a[tid-1]+1;
   ```

   note that `temp` is *thread-local* variable.  It is not shared amongst threads.  Therefore the above line of code (for threads in the else block) is using an unitialized value of `temp`.
3. The remainder of your kernel code:

   ```
       cache[cacheIndex]=temp;
       __syncthreads();
       for (int i=0;i<gen;i++)
       {
         if(cacheIndex==i)
         {
           lock. lock();
           cache[cacheIndex]=temp;
           lock.unlock();
         }
       }


   }
   ```

   does *nothing useful* because it is updating shared memory locations (i.e. `cache`) which are never transferred back to the `dev_a` variable, i.e. global memory.  Therefore none of this code could affect the results you print out.

It's difficult to follow what you are trying to accomplish in your code.  However if you change this line (the uninitialized value):

```
    int temp;
```

to this:

```
    int temp=tid+3;
```

Your code will print out the data according to what you have shown.

Comment: thank you mr Rober Crovella on your explanation. Point of my question is current thread (tid) will work after the threads [tid-1] previously completed work and the results [tid-1] will be used by current thread  [tid].could you give me an explanation so that it can be done and if you are pleased with a example code so that I can better understand. I am a beginner in cuda programming. thank you

Comment: Having each thread be dependent on the previous thread's result is fundamentally a serial approach to a problem.  The classic example is prefix sum, and an efficient parallel prefix sum looks nothing like its serial counterpart.  You should recast what you are trying to do in a parallel algorithm.  To that end, it's not clear what you want to do, other than print out a string of sequential numbers.

Comment: Could you give me your email. I have created a parallel code in cuda programming of an algorithm (this is not same as code that I have posted). but the computation time is very slow. I will show you, if you be willing to see it and give comments where my mistake. give me the solution. thank you for your attention. My email sean.c.sumarta@gmail.com

Comment: sorry, I don't hand out my email address.  If you post well-formed questions on SO, I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: thank you mr robert Crovella I know it's very personal I hope you can answer my question in this forum the next time. regards